# After my Ps Plus expired, do I keep my progress on the free games

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus, star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

I just got Battlefront 2 for free via: Ps Plus and I’m just wondering if I keep my skins, progress etc after the subscription expires,Will I keep my progress?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you keep all progress after PS Plus expires.

When PS Plus expires:

- You can no longer play Battlefront 2 until you either subscribe to PS Plus again, or buy the game.
- If you buy the game, you can no longer play online until you subscribe to PS Plus again.
- You can no longer access your Cloud saves until you subscribe to PS Plus again. Therefore you should avoid deleting saves on your PS4 unless you intend to subscribe again.